# Node.js : Stopping transfer at EOF while sending binary data through UART

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port

I'm trying to open a binary file '**./test**' and send it's contents, one byte at a time, to an external device through the UART.  The external device echos back each byte.

The regular file '**./test**' and the buffer '**dta**' in this case are both 19860 bytes in length however the code will continue to send bytes from beyond the end of buffer '**dta**' well after '**a**' becomes greater than '**dta.length**' and I can't figure out why.  Any ideas?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyAMA0", {baudrate: 115200}, false);
stats = fs.statSync(__dirname+"/test");
dta = new Buffer (stats.size);
dta = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/test");
a=0;

serialPort.open(function (error) {
    if ( error ) {
        console.log('failed to open: '+error);
    } else {
        serialPort.write(dta[a]);
    }

});

serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    a++;
    if (a < dta.length) serialPort.write(dta[a]);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but the idea that JavaScript would simply stop interpreting an `if` statement correctly is hard to believe. (Also there's no reason to initialize the "dta" variable before calling `readFileSync()`; the system will allocate the Buffer for you.)

Comment: I agree, I know it can't be the case that the evaluation is failing, it has to be something else but I'm stumped.  As far as not initializing dta, it's my understanding that the readFileSync will encode the data as a text string if I don't use a new.Buffer since the 'Binary' encoding flag is depreciated.

Comment: According to the current API docs (and in my experience), if you don't specify an encoding when you call `.readFileSync()` then you get a buffer. If you do specify an encoding, you get a string.

Comment: OK, cool.  I'm all about simplification.